# How do you compare a number with the index of first value in a DOUBLE scripted array?

Tags: java, char, arrays

For example, if I had a char array that was like this: [a b d c] The index of 'c' in this array would be (0,1). How do you compare that 0 with an integer?

Comment: Are you talking about a 1d array acting as a 2d by using indexes of [row*len + col] or some other data structure?  I'm not seeing where you'd have an index of 0,1 for a normal char array.

Comment: How do you get the index of (0,1) in your example? Can you provide some code to illustrate what you are trying to do? (See [this article](http://www.sscce.org) for some tips how to do this.)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for?

```
public class jtest
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    new jtest();
  }

  public jtest()
  {
    char[][] myChars = {{'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'}};

    // myChars[x][y]
    for (int x = 0; x < myChars.length; x++)
    {
      for (int y = 0; y < myChars[0].length; y++)
      {
        if (x == 1) // compare the index value of X with some integer
          System.out.println(myChars[x][y]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```